# How can I remove whitespaces (multiple space, tab, nextline) from the input code in Python programming?

Tags: python, newline, spaces

How can I remove whitespaces (multiple spaces, tab, nextline) from the input code in Python programming?
For example,

```
input = "p y t h o n e x e r c i s e s"
```

or

```
input = "python exercises"
```

or

```
input = "python exercises\n"
```

I want to show just a single word. That means the output will be "pythonexerecises"
How can I solve this problem using python?

Answer (score 1):

```
inp = "p y t h o n e x e r c i s e s"
out = ''.join(inp.split())
print(out)
```